# Problema ao salvar duas vendas ao mesmo tempo - JAVA

Tags: javascript, hibernate, jpa

Estou com um problema ao salvar duas vendas ao mesmo tempo em computadores diferentes, quando finaliza as duas, uma substitui a outra. Estou usando `@ManagedBean`, `@SessionScoped`.

Este é meu método `salvar()` no controller:

```
public String salvar1() {

    if (venda.getItensVenda().isEmpty()) {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                                "Não é possível gerar um orçamento sem adicionar produtos!", ""));
        return "/list?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {

        try {

            if (venda.getId() == null) {
                Long id1 = vendaFacade.listarTodos().get(0).getId();
                venda.setId(id1 + 1);
            }

            System.out.println("Aqui Entrou");
            for (int i = 0; i < venda.getItensVenda().size(); i++) {
                if (venda.getItensVenda().get(i).getId() == null) {
                    Long id3 = itemVendaFacade.listarTodos().get(0).getId();
                    Long n = (long) id3 + i + 1;
                    System.out.println("Aqui Conta");
                    venda.getItensVenda().get(i).setId(n);
                    venda.getItensVenda().get(i).setNome(venda.getItensVenda().get(i).getPlantio().getNome());

                }
            }
            if (venda.getPessoa() instanceof PessoaFisica) {
                venda.setVenda(Boolean.FALSE);
                venda.setValida("PF");
                venda.setNomeFun(venda.getFuncionario().getNome());

                vendaFacade.salvar(venda);
            } else {
                venda.setValida("PJ");
                venda.setNomeFun(venda.getFuncionario().getNome());
                venda.setVenda(Boolean.FALSE);

                vendaFacade.salvar(venda);
            }


            return "/orcamento/list?faces-redirect=true";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    addMessage(null,
                            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                                    "Ocorreu um erro no parcelamento, verifique!", ""));
            return "form?faces-redirect=true";
        }

    }
}
```

No Facade:

```
 entity = em.merge(entity);
```

Entidade:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "venda")
public class Venda implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtVenda = new Date();
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtVendaTela = new Date();
    @Column
    private String nomeFun;
    @Column
    private String cpfNota;
    @Column
    private String tipoDeVenda;
    @Column
    private String cnpjNota;
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataVencimento = new Date();
    @Column
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataAtualizacao = new Date();
    @Column
    private BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalFiscal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private Boolean fiscal;
    @Column
    private Boolean recebido = Boolean.FALSE;
    @Column
    private Boolean troca = Boolean.FALSE;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal entrada = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalDesc = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalDescFiscal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalDescEn = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal totalDescEnFiscal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal acrescimo = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal desconto = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal valorDesconto = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column
    private Boolean venda = Boolean.FALSE;
    @Column
    private String valida;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String xml;
    private Boolean naoTransmitida;
    @ManyToOne
    private Bandeira bandeira;
    @Column
    private String numeroDoc;
    @Column
    @Min(value = 1)
    private Integer qtdParcela = 1;
    @Column
    private String tipoPagamento = "A VISTA";
    @Column(length = 600)
    private String obs = "".toUpperCase();
    private String tipoDoc;
    private String agenciaC;
    private String modalidadefrete;
    private Integer intervalo = 30;
    @Column
    private Boolean vendaFiscal = Boolean.FALSE;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal creditoHaver = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column(precision = 8)
    private BigDecimal quantidadeItens = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Pessoa pessoa;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Funcionario funcionario;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Banco banco;
    private String modeloNota;
    @ManyToOne
    private PlanoContas planoContas;
    @Column
    private BigDecimal valorCheque = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private String veiculo;
    private String especie = "1";
    private String marca = "1";
    private String numeracao = "1";
    private String pesob;
    private String pesol;
    private String quantidade = "1";
    private String rntc;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "venda")
    private List<ItemVenda> itensVenda = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "venda")
    private List<Parcela> parcelas;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Empresa empresa;
    @Column
    private Boolean entregue = Boolean.FALSE;
    private Date dataVencimentoCheque;
    private String titular;
    @Column
    private Boolean vFiscal;
    @Column
    private String dtOriginal;
// gets e sets
```

Método Listar Todos:

```
public List<T> listarTodos() {
    String consulta = "FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " order by id desc";
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(consulta);
    return query.setMaxResults(20).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Como está a sua entidade `Venda`? Pode editar a pergunta e colocar o código dela aqui?

Comment: E se possível o do `VendaFacade` e do `ItemVendaFacade` também. Pelo menos os métodos `listarTodos()`.

Comment: Já estou com a minha resposta escrita pela metade, mas preciso saber o que há no `VendaFacade.salvar(Venda)` para terminar ela.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua entidade `Venda`, você já tem isso:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;
```

Ou seja, você já diz para o Hibernate para ele criar o id da entidade. Ele vai fazer isso ao confiar no fato da coluna ser `AUTO_INCREMENT` no banco de dados. Assim sendo, você basicamente diz que o banco de dados é responsável por criar os ids automaticamente.

No entanto, você faz isso:

```
            Long id1 = vendaFacade.listarTodos().get(0).getId();
            venda.setId(id1 + 1);
```

E isso:

```
                Long id3 = itemVendaFacade.listarTodos().get(0).getId();
                Long n = (long) id3 + i + 1;
                System.out.println("Aqui Conta");
                venda.getItensVenda().get(i).setId(n);
```

Ou seja, nesses lugares você está setando o id você mesmo e passando por cima do `GenerationType.IDENTITY` do hibernate e do `AUTO_INCREMENT` do banco de dados. A melhor forma de garantir que o id gerado seja único é confiar no `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Ao usar esse setter, você abre mão do `AUTO_INCREMENT` e com isso acaba praticamente pedindo para ter problemas de concorrência se duas threads estiverem executando esse método ao mesmo tempo, pois elas gerarão ids que irão colidir. Além disso, o desempenho é ruim porque você vai fazer o hibernate ler todos os registros (ou pelo menos 20 deles) com o uso do `listarTodos()`.

O melhor é você confiar no `GenerationType.IDENTITY` e no `AUTO_INCREMENT`. O id será populado quando você salvar a entidade no banco de dados com um `merge` ou `persist`.

E o seu método `salvar1()` fica assim:

```
public String salvar1() {

    if (venda.getItensVenda().isEmpty()) {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                                "Não é possível gerar um orçamento sem adicionar produtos!", ""));
        return "/list?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < venda.getItensVenda().size(); i++) {
            ItemVenda iv = venda.getItensVenda().get(i);
            if (iv.getId() == null) {
                System.out.println("Aqui Conta");
                iv.setNome(iv.getPlantio().getNome());
            }
        }
        venda.setValida(venda.getPessoa() instanceof PessoaFisica ? "PF" : "PJ");
        venda.setNomeFun(venda.getFuncionario().getNome());
        venda.setVenda(Boolean.FALSE);
        vendaFacade.salvar(venda);
        return "/orcamento/list?faces-redirect=true";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL,
                                "Ocorreu um erro no parcelamento, verifique!", ""));
        return "form?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

O hibernate já vai setar todos os ids a partir do `AUTO_INCREMENT` para todas as entidades `Venda` e `ItemVenda`. Inclusive recomendo até excluir os métodos `setId` (mas deixar os `getId`) para ficar bem claro que o id nunca deve ser setado manualmente e que apenas o hibernate pode setá-los.

Há outras mudanças que eu poderia propor para melhorar o encapsulamento e outras coisinhas, mas isso daí já foge ao escopo desta pergunta.

Comment: Cara eu fiz isso só pra teste
 public String salvarTeste() {
        synchronized (venda) {
            vendaFacade.salvarNota(venda);
            return "/orcamento/list?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

Mais sem sucesso, a primeira venda em 2 pcs ele salva as duas, se tentarmos novamente uma sobrescreve a outra.

Comment: @LeandroSantos Como e onde é que esse campo `venda` é declarado? Entidades JPA não devem nunca ser compartilhadas entre diferentes threads, e o fato de você estar usando `synchronized` dá a entender que é exatamente isso que você está fazendo.

Comment: Eu coloquei o synchronized agora pra ver se resolvia rs, mais sem sucesso. public String salvarTeste() {
        synchronized (this) {
            vendaFacade.salvarNota(venda);
            return "/orcamento/list?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }
No meu botão novo() eu só instancio um novo objeto.

Comment: @LeandroSantos Acho que para entender com detalhes a raiz do problema, você vai precisar colocar mais partes do seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Acho que atingi o maximo de caracteres, mais posso jogar em um dontPad pode ser

Comment: @LeandroSantos Sim, pode ser.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80473/discussion-between-leandro-santos-and-victor-stafusa).